# Visual Studio Code Error Validator Eslint

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, syntax-error, eslint

I want to be aware of current errrors in my React/NextJs project. How can I set up my VSC to highlight at least basic errors e.g. unused/undefined variables. I installed Eslint as extension, furthermore I have .eslint.json file in my project with the following content:
{
"extends": "next/core-web-vitals"
}
Eslint shows some errors in terminal e.g. ,,Cannot find module 'next/babel' ". I want to point out that I have only 3 extesions in vsc: Prettier, JS (ES6) and Eslint.  I would be extremely grateful if someone told me how get I solve this problem...I guess that the only way to validate errros in vsc is Eslint ? Anyway how can I set it to show at least basic errors ?

To resolve ,,babel problem":

1. in .eslint.json I put:

`"extends": [ "next"`

2. Create .babelrc file containing:

{
"presets": [
"next/babel"
],
"plugins": []
}

3. Create workdir settings.json :

   "eslint.workingDirectories": [
   {
   "pattern": "app/*/"
   },
   {
   "pattern": "packages/*/"
   }
   ]

With this settings eslint shows  some errors but not he most important. It still doesn't show undef variables...I can type random text in randomn place and VSC doesn't catch error.